# First Time To Run C++ Program on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++

What is the command to run the following simple C++ program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// main () is where program execution begins
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World";        // prints Hello World

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

First you need to *compile and link* your program. Assuming the source code is saved in a file `yourprog.cpp`, you can do that using the GNU C++ compiler `g++`, for example

```
g++ -Wall -o yourprog yourprog.cpp
```

The resulting executable will be called `yourprog` and you can then run it using

```
./yourprog
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essentials` is probably needed, too. ;-)

Comment: Not really - since the OP isn't using `make`, and the dependency tree for `g++` should pull in the standard libs. Also, it's called `build-essential` (singular).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to use `make` to build and run your program without requiring any additional setup:

```
make CXXFLAGS='-Wall -Werror' hello_world && ./hello_world
```

But assuming you will continue developing, you will want to create a file called `Makefile` to streamline things further.

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
default: build
build: hello_world
run: build
<tab>./hello_world
```

Then you can build and run your program by typing:

```
make run
```

If you just want to see if your program compiles without error, type:

```
make
```

Other notes:

- The `<tab>` above should be created using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.
- It is important to include `-Wall -Werror`.  These flags prevent certain obvious programming bugs from being ignored by the compiler.  That means less debugging work for the programmer.
- I advocate the use of the `-s` option with `make`.  It eliminates (usually) unnecessary verbosity.
- One feature of `make` is that it doesn't recompile your program if it doesn't need to.  This can be a nice time-saver if the program takes a long time to compile.  This is especially useful if your project has more than one source (.cpp) file, since these can be compiled independently -- and even in parallel (simultaneously) with the `-j` option.

Comment: See also: `binfmtc`

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and execute the following

1- `g++ -o outfilename.bin source.cpp`

2- `./outfilename.bin`

that assumes the source file is source.cpp

Answer (score 0):

- Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- Install GNU C++ Compiler by running following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install g++
  ```
- Now compile the cpp source file by running this command:

  ```
  g++ sourceFile.cpp -o anything
  ```
- You can now run the file like this:

  ```
  ./anything
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nifty package called [binfmtc](https://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/binfmtc.html.en) that allows you to run C++ files as if if they were "scripts" -- not requiring an explicit compilation step.

Once the `binfmtc` package is installed, your source file needs a `/*BINFMTCXX: ...` header comment (see example) and mark the `.cpp` file as executable using `chmod +x`.

```cpp
/*BINFMTCXX: -Wall -Werror
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// main () is where program execution begins
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World";        // prints Hello World

  return 0;
}
```

Setup steps:

```
$ sudo apt install binfmtc
$ chmod +x ./first-time-to-run-c-program-on-ubuntu-14-04.cpp
```

Running the "script":

```
$ ./first-time-to-run-c-program-on-ubuntu-14-04.cpp
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you save it to a file, most likely by pressing <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd>, then compile it. To compile it, run the following command:

```
g++ path/to/that/file.cpp -o path/to/output/file.out
```

Then just drag the output file to the terminal window to run it, because it is now an executable file.

You need to use `g++` because c++ is a compiled language, meaning you need a compiler to compile it into machine code. This results in c++ being a faster language than others.